# KOTLIN and MOCKK UUID test

Tags: kotlin, static, mocking, uuid, mockk

This is a Kotlin-Mockk based testcase, where I am trying to get the static class "UUID" to be mocked.

this works when used to get random string but not UUID

> mockkStatic(UUID::class)
> every { UUID.randomUUID().toString() } returnsMany uuidSource

```
//This is the uuid source 
val uuidSource = listOf(
    UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    UUID.randomUUID().toString()
)
```

In the below case it works

```
@Test
    fun x1() {
        mockkStatic(UUID::class)
        every { UUID.randomUUID().toString() } returnsMany  uuidSource

        listOf(1, 2, 3). forEach { _ ->
            println(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        }
    }
```

//But in the below case it does give error

> Unable to make private static long java.util.UUID.parse4Nibbles(java.lang.String,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2aae9190

```
@Test fun x1() {
     mockkStatic(UUID::class) every { UUID.randomUUID().toString() } returnsMany         uuidSource
        listOf(1, 2, 3). forEach { _ ->
            println(UUID.randomUUID())
        }
    }
```

Any solution for the second case to work, or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In first case you are accessing `toString()` function of `randomUUID()` so mock it worked. Where in second case you are accessing `randomUUID()` while mocking `randomUUID().toString()`.

Instead of mocking `randomUUID().toString()`, mock the `randomUUID()` itself.

```
val uuidSource = listOf(
    UUID.fromString("350e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"),
    UUID.fromString("450e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"),
    UUID.fromString("550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"),
)


@Test fun x1() {
    mockkStatic(UUID::class) 
    every { UUID.randomUUID() } returnsMany uuidSource

    listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach { _ -> println(UUID.randomUUID()) }
}
```

Here we have to use `UUID.fromString()` in `uuidSource` as `UUID.randomUUID()` return type is `UUID`.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private static long java.util.UUID.parse4Nibbles(java.lang.String,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @271053e1